# Relationship Literary Term

Tags: expressions

What is it called in text when a character refers to someone as "son of_____" or "descendant of_____". Like when they refer to a person as the relation to someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specific but very common case where a character is identified indirectly by the direct naming of his or her father, it is called using a *[patronymic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronymic),* e.g., “Atreides” or “the son of Atreus” for Agamemnon. Patronymics are also prominent in the personal naming of Russians and Icelanders.